# Azure Function App from the Docker image doesnt show functions in the Az portal page

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-docker

I try to create my first dummy Azure Function App from the Docker container.

The issue is that after creation from the published docker image, I can see the default page, but I do not see any functions (the default function should be displayed).

The function also does not work. When I enter the function HTTP, the Error 404 is returned.

*default page*

[image]

*empty function list*
[image]

Here is my setup, I am using default configuration only.

```
# Create the default azure function app.
py -m venv .venv
.venv\scripts\activate
func init --worker-runtime python --docker

# Build with the docker.
docker build -f Dockerfile -t <function-app-name> .

# Verify, that the function is working.
docker run -p 8080:80 --name <name> <function-app-name>
http://localhost:8080/api/PythonFunctionExample

# Push image into the azure docker container.
docker login <docker-container-address>.azurecr.io
docker tag <docker-tag> <docker-container-address>.azurecr.io/<function-app-name>
docker push <docker-container-address>.azurecr.io/<function-app-name>

# I Created Azure Function App from the Azure Portal.
## Docker image was selected from the Docker container registry.
## Azure Plan "Functions Premium" was selected.
```

Any idea what might be an issue, what did I forgot?

Comment: Sorry, but it seems like you created the function app, and you created the docker image which you pushed to ACR, but where did you publish / push the docker image to the function itself

Comment: The azure function app was created in the Azure portal and I selected that it should use the functions from the docker image that I selected in the azure app configuration wizard. The image is working locally but Azure probably does not recognized the functions within the docker image. I don't know how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Anything in the logs? I assume this is an HTTP trigger?

Answer (score 2):

You should select the **App Service Plan(Premium V2 P1v2)**  not **Functions Premium** for the Docker container function because the Premium Function are serverless function.